# Bundled Products Not Showing

Tags: magento-1.7, magmi, bundle

I'm trying to create an automated import system for a client's epos system using Magmi, and as far as I can tell it's correctly generating the data. However, I can't get any bundled products to show in the front end or the search, even if I create one manually.

The bundles are set to be enabled, have visibility set to catalog and search and are marked as in stock in the inventory section. The products in the bundle are all the same, in stock, visible and enabled. I've also made sure the bundle has a category set which is visible in the front end, but nothing I do seems to make any difference to whether it's visible. Is there something I need to do to enable the option of bundled products or something?

Any help is appreciated

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I've also cleared the cash and re-indexed, both through Magento itself and using the command line

Comment: Having same issue with Magento 1.8.1, have you ever managed to fix this?

Comment: It was a while back, but I think the issue was a bug with the product creation and saving the product in the admin section fixed it. This wasn't really an issue for us because any new products needed edited before they were shown

Comment: I see, so it was probably an indexing issue. Unfortunately, saving the product in the backend doesn't fix the issue for me.